# How to check if a string contains certain characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get Ruby to search a text for certain characters, such as `#` and `$`. I then want to capture the character and the text beside it until there is white space, so if I would put this as text:

```
Hey, I am a #string and #what are you?
```

It would return the index at where the `#string` and `#what` are. This line only returns if the text has a special character:

```
<div class='tweet-text'>                
    <% if feed.text.match(/#\w+/) %>
        Hi
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The point here is I want to color the "#" word to a different color. The code is inside ejs. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a pure Ruby solution or do you use Ruby on Rails?

Comment: I use Ruby on rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to highlight or mark one or more phrases in a text then you might want to have a look at the [`highlight`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-highlight) view helper:

For example

```
<%= highlight('Hey, I am a #string and #what are you?', /#\w+/) %>
```

will return

```
Hey, I am a <mark>#string</mark> and <mark>#what</mark> are you?
```

Comment: This works, although is it possible to get it to also show as link?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation (link in my answer) there are several examples for different use-cases. Two examples show how to insert links. The syntax depends a bit on where and how you want to link to.